# safe to sear beef tenderloin the night before?

Tags: food-safety, beef

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I Brown Beef For Slow Cooking the Night Before](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7552/can-i-brown-beef-for-slow-cooking-the-night-before)

I would like to prep my Beef Wellington the night before.  I would sear, cover with mushrooms, prosciutto the night before, refrigerate overnight then wrap in pastry the next day before cooking.  Is this safe?

Comment: See duplicate - the USDA recommends not to partially-cook beef, so just treat the browned beef as raw, sear it quickly, refrigerate immediately after searing, and cook it thoroughly the next day.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, should be safe, provided your beef was fresh before preperation.